# Fixing slope movment of 2D controller(Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, controller, 2d

i'm coding a 2D controller for a character in unity.
Is my first time working without the phyisics nor rigidbody and i'm a bit lost. Right now my controller works well in flat surfaces (vertical and horizontal),but i'm having problem with slopes.

First i call move in update with a Vector2 with x and y speed.

Here is the code:

'''

```
public void Move(Vector2 velocity){
    localVelocity = velocity;
    transform.Translate (localVelocity);
    grounded= false;
    characterCollsions ();
}
```

'''

Here the collisions check:

'''

```
public void characterCollsions (){
Collider2D[] hitElements = Physics2D.OverlapBoxAll(transform.position, boxCollider.size, 0, playerColisionsLayer);

    foreach (Collider2D hit in hitElements)
    {

        //Let's exclude his own hitbox
        if (hit == boxCollider)
            continue;


            ColliderDistance2D colliderDistance = hit.Distance(boxCollider);
            DebugDraw.DrawMarker(colliderDistance.pointA,1.0f, Color.red, 0.0f, false);
            Debug.DrawRay(transform.position,colliderDistance.normal);

            if (colliderDistance.isOverlapped)
            {

                //if the character is inside the collider get it out
                transform.Translate(colliderDistance.pointA - colliderDistance.pointB);

               //Check for ground

                if (Vector2.Angle(colliderDistance.normal, Vector2.up) <90 )
                {   

                    collision.below = true;
                    anim.SetBool("isGrounded",true);
                    grounded = true; 

                }

            }


    }

}
```

'''

This creates 2 problems in the slope, the character "jumps" when going down, and slides down when standing still. I tried to setting the velocity.y to 0 when standing on the slope but it doesn't work.

Edit:
Gif with both problems
https://gyazo.com/7137f60096a297d28eb7d12cb49d7eaa

Comment: Can you show a gif of your character "jumping" when going down?

Comment: Sure, added a gif at the end of the original post.

Comment: Have you taken a look at this solution offered in the Unity Forums? https://answers.unity.com/questions/1086765/any-relatively-simple-way-to-handle-2d-slopes-with.html With a video tutorial provided: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xMhgxUFKakQ

Comment: Did you find a solution ?